# Why does an open ended wire cause the load to the oscillator to increase?

Tags: electric-circuits, oscillators, electronics, electrical-engineering

Using an ammeter between the wall and signal generator, I noticed that when the lead from a single channel is attached to the signal generator, the power into the signal generator increases by about 100 milliwatts.

When the wire leads are removed from the signal generator, the input power into the signal generator decreases by 100 milliwatts.

Why would an open ended wire cause a load? Is there a way for that wire not to add to the input load?

The lead wire from the signal generator is not attached to anything on the open end.

Comment: How long is the wire and what signal are you generating? (in particular, what frequency?)

Comment: Irregardless of the frequency. The actual input to load of course changes with frequency but there is always a 100 milliwatt difference between having the lead wire attached and not attached.

Comment: Then this seems like it's more likely to do with the signal generator's internal design and not with a conceptual physics question. You might get a better/faster answer by asking this question on the Electronics Stack Exchange (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) and including the details of the signal generator in the question.

Comment: I tested and any wire added, adds to the load but none as much as the original Duel leads of positive and negative joined in a single insulation. Perhaps capacitive coupling? Standing waves? Just odd for a wire in an open circuit to add that much to the load. Lead wires are 42 inches in length

Comment: Every circuit question should have a diagram. Please post a diagram of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are waves in the wire, and they can be reflected back from the closure.

As an example: when I was working with preamplifiers to increase the signal measured in the oscilloscope, I had to use a 50 ohm closure at the end of every wire, to get a good enough reflection otherwise the signal kind of "leaked" , got noisy.

I guess some electrodynamics calculation could show you what's going on! :D

Comment: But wouldn't this give a frequency-dependent load? According to the OP, his results were independent of frequency.

Comment: Yes it will be frequency dependent, but nonlinear and it also saturates, so above or below some limit it looks like as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that someone who is familiar with RF answered my question elsewhere. His answer was that the attached BnC cable to the signal generator is not an open circuit as I has assumed but because of the Mhz frequency, it actually appears to the signal generator as a mismatched circuit (impedance mismatch) drawing a load.

The signal generator is rated at a 50 ohm impedance and the BnC connector is also 50 ohms. So perhaps it simply sees it as a matched impedance load?